# Is $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ is cyclic ? Yes/No

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Is $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$  is cyclic ?

My attempt :$\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ is not cyclic  because gcd$(2,2) \neq 1$

Is  it  true  ?

Comment: Yes I think you are using the lemma that says a finite  product of cyclic groups is cyclic if and only if the orders of the factors are all coprime. Alternatively you can inspect the group and see there is no element of order $4$.

Comment: Yes, the lemma @Yorch mentions is overkill. Just check the order of each element.

Comment: Why do you think $\gcd(2, 2)\neq1$ implies it is not cyclic? This is true, but it would be helpful if you explained to us/yourself *why* it is true, or at least what you think the connection might be.

Comment: Why not just write out each element and compute its order?  There are only $4$ of them, after all.

Comment: @user1729  because  there  are $2$  element  in $ \mathbb{Z_2} \times \mathbb{Z_2} $  have order $2$

Comment: @jasmine What does that have to do with being cyclic? (It also isn't true - there are $3$ elements of order $2$).

Comment: perhaps that $\mathbb Z_4$ has exactly one element of order $2$, so if you find $2$ it's way too much  @user1729

Comment: @Yorch The point of my comment(s) was to encourage the OP to think and explain themselves, by themselves

Comment: @Yorch Ah, it is difficult to be terse, accurate, and unambiguously polite!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a group of order $n$ to be cyclic, it has to have an element of order $n$. Does this group have such an element?

The main thing that is insufficient with your attempt is that we do not have any idea if you know some relationship between the gcd and whether or not $\mathbb Z_n\times \mathbb Z_m$ is cyclic.  It is entirely possible you are grasping at some random fact you do not really know is true or not.  You really ought to clearly state what proposition you are leveraging if the proposition is going to be the workhorse of your proof.